# Measurable function associated to a family of Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $\{(X_t, \|.\|_t) : t \in [0, 1]\}$ is a family of Banach spaces, and let $f, g$ be functions defined on $[0, 1]$ such that $f(t), g(t) \in X_t$, for each $t \in [0, 1]$.

Suppose further that the functions
\begin{eqnarray*}
t \mapsto \|f(t)\|_t\\
t \mapsto \|g(t)\|_t
\end{eqnarray*}

$t \in [0, 1]$, are measurable. Is it true that the function $t \mapsto \|f(t) + g(t)\|_t$ will be measurable?

Comment: Nope. You can construct cases such that the first two are constant while the sum is poorly behaved.

Comment: Most interestingly, it already fails for $X_t \equiv \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ be a Banach space.  Let $\{(X_t, \|\cdot\|_t) : t \in [0, 1]\}$ is a family of Banach spaces, such that, for all $t \in [0, 1]$, $X_t=X$ and $\|\cdot\|_t=\|\cdot\|$.

Let $u\in X$ be a vector such that $\|u\|=1$ and let $E\subseteq [0,1]$ be a non-measurable set.  Define the function $f$ by , for all $t\in [0,1]$, $f(t)=u$ and define the function $g$ by $g(t)=u$, if $t\in E$ and  $g(t)=-u$, if $t\in [0,1]-E$.

Then  the functions
\begin{eqnarray*}
t \mapsto \|f(t)\|_t=1\\
t \mapsto \|g(t)\|_t=1
\end{eqnarray*}
$t \in [0, 1]$, are measurable (both are constant functions), but we have, 
$\|f(t) + g(t)\|_t= 2$, if $t\in E$ and $\|f(t) + g(t)\|_t= 0$ if $t\in [0,1]- E$.  So the function $t \mapsto \|f(t) + g(t)\|_t$ is NOT measurable.

Comment: Your example used non-measurable sets/functions. What would happen in the following scenario: suppose the spaces $\{X_t : t [0, 1]\}$ have a non-zero common intersection (they could be all the same linear space, for example), and you have two distinct elements $a, b$ in this intersection such that the functions $t \mapsto \|a\|_t, \|b\|_t$ are measurable. Is it possible to find two measurable functions $\varphi, \psi : [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $f = \varphi a$ and $g = \psi b$ show the same behaviour of your example?

Comment: @WillianCorrêa This new question is a completely different scenario. If, for all $t\in [0,1]$ , $(X_t,\|\cdot\|_t)=(X,\|\cdot\|)$, then consider $Y$ the linear space generated by $\{a, b\}$.  $Y$ has dimension at most $2$, so it is a  closed subspace of $X$ and it is a Banach space with the norm $\|\cdot\|$. Since $\varphi, \psi:[0,1] \to \mathbb{C}$ are measurable functions, we have that $f=\varphi a$ and $g = \psi b$ are measurable functions from $[0,1]$ to $Y$. So $f+g$  is a measurable function from $[0,1]$ to $Y$. So the function $t\to \|f(t)+g(t)\|$ is measurable.

Comment: Yes, that is true, however I'm supposing that $X_t = X$ for all $t \in [0,1]$ just as a linear space, that is, the norms might be different.

Comment: @WillianCorrêa If the norm may be different, then we can build an example with the same behaviour. For all $t\in [0,1]$, $X=\mathbb{R}^2$ (or $\mathbb{C}^2$, if you prefer). Consider $$\|(x,y)\|_S=|x|+|y|$$ and $$\|(x,y)\|_M=\max\{|x|,|y|\}$$  Let $E$ be a NON-measurable subset of $[0,1]$ and define, for each $t\in [0,1]$, $$\|\cdot\|_t =\|\cdot\|_S \textrm{, if } t\in E$$ and $$\|\cdot\|_t= \|\cdot\|_M \textrm{, if } t\in [0,1]-E$$ (CONTINUE)

Comment: Let $a=(1,0)$ and $b=(0,1)$. Let $f$ and $g$ be functions defined by, for all $t\in [0,1]$, $f(t)=a$ and $g(t)=b$. Then $t\to \|f(t)\|_t=\|a\|_t=1$ and $t\to \|g(t)\|_t=\|b\|_t=1$ are constant functions and they are measurable. HOWEVER, for all $t\in [0,1]$, $$\|a+b\|_t =\|a+b\|_S=2 \textrm{, if } t\in E$$ and $$\|a+b\|_t= \|a+b\|_M=1 \textrm{, if } t\in [0,1]-E$$ So the function $t\to \|f(t)+g(t)\|_t=\|a+b\|_t$ is not measurable.